# View Azure Blob Metadata Online

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to examine an Azure blob's metadata through a web interface or the Azure portal?

I'm running into a problem where I set metadata on a blob programmatically, without any problems, but when I go back to read the metadata in another section of the program there isn't any. So I'd like to confirm that the metadata was, in fact, written to the cloud.

Comment: Please share the code for both setting the metadata & reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the simplest ways to set/get an Azure Storage Blob's metadata is by using the cross-platform [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/), which is a standalone app from Microsoft that allows you to easily work with Azure Storage data on Windows, macOS and Linux.

Just right click on the blob you want to examine and select Properties, you will see the metadata list if they exist.

[image]

Note: Version tested - **0.8.7**

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to check this on the portal, however you can try the [Storage Explorer tool](http://storageexplorer.com/).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check the metadata in your code, please try this [Get blob metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/get-blob-metadata)